# Не работает поиск в Django

Tags: html, django, search, jinja2

Если честно, не могу представить даже в чём проблема. Джанго показывает ошибку "Page not found(404)", и решить я её сам не могу. `models.py`(Таблица с инфрмацией про блюдо.):

```py
    class Product(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      description = models.TextField(blank=False)
      price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/")
```

Часть `html` кода с полем поиска:

```
<form action="{}" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <button type="submit"><img src="{% static 'products/img/search.svg %}" class="search-icon" alt=""></button>
      </form>
```

`views.py` у меня содержит вот такой код:

```py
    def products(request):
      meals = Product.objects.all()
      return render(
        request,
          'products.html',
          {'meals' : meals,},
      )
    
    class Search():
      def search(request):
        if "q" in request.GET:
          q = request.GET['q']
          multiple_query = Q(Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(description__icontains=q))
          prdct = Product.objects.filter(multiple_query)
        else:
          prdct = Product.objects.all()
          context = {'prdct' : prdct,}
        return render(request, 'products.html', context)
```

`urls.py`:

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', products, name='products'),
    ]
```

У меня есть предположение, что нужно что-то либо дописать на дзиндзе в HTML, либо в url'ах, ведь ошибка не видит именно страницы с адресом `"127.0.0.1:8000/products/{}?q=Название"`, только вот что туда дописывать, когда цель заключается в том, чтобы неподходящие под критерии поиска товары пропадали со страницы, которая уже есть, я не знаю.

Сама ошибка:

[image: Ошибка 404]

И ещё, попросил бы объяснять вещи более подробно, ведь адекватных гайдов по реализации такого поиска я найти не смог, так что и его работу понимаю плоховато. Если же вы знаете хороший гайд по написанию такого функционала, был бы благодарен если добавите к ответу

upd. Только что увидел что в action тэга form у меня пусто, просто {}, думаю если вы подскажете что там должно быть по дзиндзе прописано, вопрос будет исчерпан.

upd2. Если сам action убрать, то ошибка пропадёт, но поиск всё равно работать не будет. Ссылка будет меняться, а содержание - нет.

Comment: У вас только в блоке else продукты добавляются в контекст.

Comment: Дублировал context и в if, никаких изменений не последовало